# Differentiate the integral of a piecewise continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, terminology

Given that f(x) is a piecewise cts function. Is it correct to say that $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(y)dy$ is almost continuously differentiable everywhere? Is it correct that $\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x)$?

Edit: A follow up question:
In this [proof](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eangenent/519.2016s/notes/picard.html), under "Proving that the limit is a solution", how comes "Therefore x(t) is differentiable"?

---

Answer (score 0):

Rather than "almost continuously differentiable everywhere" I would say "continuously differentiable almost everywhere"!

The problem with saying $\frac{dF}{dx}= f$ is that while the derivative of a function is not necessarily continuous, it does satisfy the "intermediate value property" that if $f(x_0)\le y\le f(x_1)$ then there exist x between $x_0$ and $x_1$ such that y= f(x).  So $\frac{dF}{dx}= f$ can only be true if f has that property.

Comment: In a search on MathSci I found only six reviews that used the phrase "continuously differentiable almost everywhere."  So the phrase is in use.  In this particular case, since $f$ is piecewise continuous, there are only finitely many points of concern and the phrase seems like overkill and "piecewise smooth" seems more likely.

Answer (score 0):

As $f$ is piecewise continuous, it is continuous at all but finitely many points. $F$ is differentiable by FTC, and this is continuous at all but those points where $f$ is not continuous.

On the second part of your question, it is not correct unless $f$ is continuous over that interval. If $f$ has a jump, then its integral will have a "corner" in it, so will not be differentiable.

Comment: Seems confused.  If $f$ is continuous then $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ is indeed "continuously differentiable" since $F'(x)=f(x)$ everywhere.  If it happens that $f$ is continuous but nowhere differentiable that only asserts that $F''$ exists nowhere.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson You're of course completely right, don't know what I was trying to say there. I will edit my answer!

Answer (score -1):

First off, it is not correct to say continuously differentiable as differentiability implies continuity. It would just be if the function f(x) is differentiable everywhere.

Secondly, we can not assume that the function is differentiable everywhere as we are not given any more information. In some cases, piecewise functions include cusps or corners, or vertical tangents. That would determine if the function is differentiable or not.

Thirdly, it is correct to say that F'(x) = f(x) since you substitute the x into the y variable. As long as the function is differentiable.

Comment: It seems like you are suggesting that continuously differentiable means differentiable, which is not the case – it means that the derivative is continuous.